# Bitcore payment protocol

Tags: bitcore

I'm stuck with the BIP70 documentation. I can't figure out how to translate the repeated fields on that object.

```
    message PaymentDetails {
         optional string network = 1 [default = "main"];
         repeated Output outputs = 2;
         required uint64 time = 3;
         optional uint64 expires = 4;
         optional string memo = 5;
         optional string payment_url = 6;
         optional bytes merchant_data = 7;
    }
```

With the bitcore-payment-protocol npm package, here is how they fill the outputs filled in the docs.

```
    var details = new PaymentProtocol().makePaymentDetails();
    details.set('network', 'test');
    details.set('outputs', outputs);<=== shall ouputs be an array?
    details.set('time', now);
    details.set('expires', now + 60 * 60 * 24);
    details.set('memo', 'A payment request from Ambrosia.');
    details.set('payment_url', 'https://localhost/-/pay');
    details.set('merchant_data', new Buffer({size: 7}));
```

Here is my question, I want more than one output, should I fill it with an array of output object?